# jQuery function calculation wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function

```
$("#exchange").on("change", function() {
    var am = $(this).val();
    var fee = $("#fee").val();
    var cost = $("#cost").val();
    var perc = fee / 100;
    var tot = perc * am;
    var fea = parseFloat(tot) + parseFloat(cost);
    var total = parseFloat(am) - parseFloat(tot) - parseFloat(cost);
    $("#return").val(total.toFixed(2));
    $("#due").val("$" + fea.toFixed(2));
});
$("#return").on("change", function() {
    var am = $(this).val();
    var fee = $("#fee").val();
    var cost = $("#cost").val();
    var perc = fee / 100;
    var tot = perc * am;
    var fea = parseFloat(tot) + parseFloat(cost);
    var total = parseFloat(am) + parseFloat(tot) + parseFloat(cost);
    $("#exchange").val(total.toFixed(2));
    $("#due").val("$" + fea.toFixed(2));
});
```

for example if `#exchange` = 16.85, `#fee` = 11, and `#cost` = 0

it should calculate `#due` = $1.85 and `#return` = 15.00

which is all correct. The problem is working in reverse I need it to calculate the same way but instead right now I get this

`#return` = 15, `#fee` = 11, and `#cost` = 0

it calculates `#due` = $1.65 and `#exchange` = 16.65

I understand why it is doing that, because it is calculating the fees from the `var am` which is the value of that field, which makes it very difficult for me to accomplish what I am trying to achieve which is to make it the same both ways, but obviously I cannot call `var am` to be the value of `#exchange` in my `#return` function because the field would be blank at that time which would calculate it at `NAN` so what can I do to make it to where all of my calculations are the same both ways, I have been trying for the better part of 5 hours to figure out what to do, but I am lost, a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var perc = fee / 100;` did you check if this part is done correctly? instead of using `parseFloat()` in the calculations - just use it when you read the values.

Comment: @LiranBo Yes it is done correctly, and everything shows correctly as far as the calculations goes, the issue is that I want the calculations to be the same both ways, if `#exchange` = 16.85 that makes `#fee` = 1.85 and `#return` = 15 but if you put `#return` = 15 it takes the 11% from it making the fee only 1.65 but it should be 1.85 but I am not sure how to make it calculate the amounts the same.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't read everything then. from my experience the best way to do something like that is to simply save the number before the exchange, and on the return you return that number. because when you deal with float type it will be very hard to go back to the exact previous value. meaning the clicking the exchange & return buttons over and over again could change the original number dramatically.

Comment: if you can set a fiddle with a simple example I can show you what I mean

Comment: @LiranBo https://jsfiddle.net/zrmaqkjq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple problem with your algebra to me.  I see what you are trying to do.  As it stands, you assume `return = exchange - tot - cost` and `exchange = return + tot + cost`.  The problem is that you have assumed `var tot` is the same in your solution working forward and your solution working in reverse.

However, `tot` is equal to `(fee/100) * exchange` working forward and `(fee/100) * return` working backward, which breaks your assumptions for how to calculate `exchange` and `return`.  My first step would be to move away from the `var am` assignment and naming, which seems to be confusing you, and call each `exchange` and `return` what they really are.  This might help you form a correct algebraic solution, which you can then implement in JavaScript.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6hrLbmc/

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong formula.

Use `brutto=netto/(1-fee/100)` instead of `brutto=netto*(1+fee/100)`

You have to distinguish whether the fee is applied to netto (`+netto*fee/100`) or to brutto (`-brutto*fee/100`).

Comment: here is a jsfiddle so you can see how the snippet works in action because I am not fully understanding what you are saying
https://jsfiddle.net/zrmaqkjq/

Comment: `15/0.89` vs `15*1.11`